# Connection pooling in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

In Mongo and HBase, we have a way to track the client connection, Is there a way to get the total client connection in Cassandra?

Answer (score 1):

On client-side Datastax driver reports metrics on connections, task queues, queries and errors (connection errors, r/w timeouts, retries, speculative executions).

Can be accessed via the `Cluster.getMetrics()` operation (java).

Comment: Thanks @Ralkie, Can you please provide the nodejs implementation for this in apache cassandra.

Answer (score 0):

Datastax provides a cassandra structure, CassMetrics (cpp driver). This structure contains min and max microseconds to execute a query, pending requests, timed-out requests, total connections and available connections. It gives the entire performance metrics of a particular snapshot of the session.

Each member of the structure is explained clearly in the following datastax documentation- https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/cpp-driver/2.3/api/struct.CassMetrics/

Here, is an example program on how to use the structure effectively - https://github.com/datastax/cpp-driver/blob/master/examples/perf/perf.c

Comment: Thanks @Chakri, Can you please provide the nodejs implementation for this in apache cassandra.

Comment: http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/nodejs-driver/3.3/api/type.ClientOptions/ I think this will help you